# Any way to generate <link>'ed instead of inline stylesheets from Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

If I have the following code in a webpack project with `css-loader` and `style-loader` plugins:

```
import 'index.css'
```

It generates an inline style in a `<style>` tag. Is there any way to leverage browser caching feature by having it generate a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">` instead? I know I can put CSS files in the public folder, but then it won't be in the Webpack build pipeline. Is there some existing CSS loader plugin that does this? Or are there strong arguments for abandoning this approach altogether (ofc. not putting them render-blockingly in the document `<head>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no arguments against this. I would even say this is more common than to leave the css in the chunks. But you need to use a plugin for this.

Until recently the go to here was [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), but now if you are using webpack 4 I would suggest [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).

You might want to turn this off for local development. It gets in the way of HMR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer & the pointers to these plugins. I had hoped there to be a straightforward way (e.g. like with Gulp) to simply copy a file from `src` to `build`. With `create-react-app` [tweaking the Webpack config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3917) is nigh-impossible.

Comment: @Tyblitz Webpack does a lot of cool things for you in addition to just copying, like proper splitting for routes, resolving of assets in css, naming the files with hashes for caching and loading them correctly. I dislike the philosophy of `create-react-app` here a lot.. but I guess if you don't want to eject there is not a lot you can do.